# Retrieving map of struct instead of slice of struct using yaml.v2

Tags: go, struct, yaml, slice

I have a yaml file which has the following structure which cannot be changed.

```
fruit:
  - cost: 10
    name: apple
  - cost: 20
    name: banana
```

I have created the following struct for the same:

```
type T struct {
    Fruit []struct {
        Cost int    `yaml:"cost"`
        Name string `yaml:"name"`
    } `yaml:"fruit"`
}
```

When I unmarshal the yaml to the struct using yaml.v2, I rightly get the following:

```
{[{10 apple} {20 banana}]}
```

Is there a way that I can get map of struct so that I don't have to loop over the slice again and again just to find the cost of the apple:

```
{map[apple:{apple 10} banana:{banana 20}]}}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can implement custom [Unmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Unmarshaler)

```
type T struct {
    Fruit map[string]Fruit
}

type Fruit struct {
    Cost int    `yaml:"cost"`
    Name string `yaml:"name"`
}

func (t *T) UnmarshalYAML(unmarshal func(interface{}) error) error {
    var tmpStruct struct {
        Fruit []Fruit `yaml:"fruit"`
    }

    err := unmarshal(&tmpStruct)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    fruit := make(map[string]Fruit, len(tmpStruct.Fruit))
    for _, f := range tmpStruct.Fruit {
        fruit[f.Name] = f
    }
    
    *t = T{Fruit: fruit}
    return nil
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://play.golang.org/p/cGyGcxboICX)</kbd>